# Using respectively twice for sequences of 3-tuples

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

Describing the 2-tuple sequence `[(A, first), (B, second), (C, third)]` is easy enough:

> A, B, and C are *respectively* the first, second, and third letters of the alphabet.

What shall be done about 3-tuple sequences such as `[(A, first, /ˈeɪ/), (B, second, /ˈbiː/), (C, third, /ˈsiː/)]`?

> A, B, and C are *respectively* the first, second, and third letters of the alphabet, and are *respectively* pronounced as /ˈeɪ/, /ˈbiː/, and /ˈsiː/.

Is the above correct, or should the second *respectively* be omitted?

---

To be clear, this question is intended to generalize to *any* 3-tuple sequence, including `[(Alice, Australia, apple), (Bob, Britain, banana), (Candice, Canada, candy)]`:

> Alice, Bob, and Candice are *respectively* from Australia, Britain, and Canada, and *respectively* most enjoy eating apples, bananas, and candy.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with adding a second _respectively_ for the purpose of clarity, but I think this could be obviated. _A, B, and C are respectively the first, second, and third letters of the alphabet, pronounced  /ˈeɪ/, /ˈbiː/, and /ˈsiː/ in that order._

Comment: Do people need to be told what order the letters of the alphabet come in? It depends on whether it's important to specify the order or if you can leave people to infer the likely order. If necessary, you can include *respectively* as often as you like, although I'm not sure you'll find a grammar book formally licensing that usage (because not every thing that is allowed is important enough to be listed).

Comment: A, B, and C are the first three letters of the alphabet and are pronounced /ˈeɪ/, /ˈbiː/, and /ˈsiː/.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use plain English: *Alice from Australia enjoys apples; Bob from Britain enjoys bananas; Candace from Canada enjoys candy.*

Comment: The simple answer is that we wouldn't normally write something like this, because it's confusing to keep track of all the things that are respective to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The second "respectively" is indeed optional, but "respectively" usually comes at the *end* of a list, giving you:

> A, B, and C are the first, second, and third letters of the alphabet, and are pronounced as /ˈeɪ/, /ˈbiː/, and /ˈsiː/, respectively.